# Error 0x800B0100 when packing a console app into MSIX package

Tags: c++, visual-studio, certificate, msix

I want to publish my first console application for windows store, and store want me Package application and when I use misx package tools it Requests certification
I use visual studio in 2019.
how to package console in visual studio with c++

[image: misx package tools]

[image: certification request]

[image: error because he requests certification]

[image: error set up]

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Docs, [Error 0x800B0100](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting?context=%252fwindows%252fmsix%252frender) means that No signature is present in the subject. You may get this error if the package is unsigned or the signature isn't valid. The package must be signed to be deployed.

So, you could refer to this link about [how to sign an app package using SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool).

- Step 1: Determine the hash algorithm to use

When you sign the app package, you must use the same hash algorithm that you used when you created the app package. If you used default settings to create the app package, the hash algorithm used is SHA256.

If you used the app packager with a specific hash algorithm to create the app package, use the same algorithm to sign the package. To determine the hash algorithm to use for signing a package, you can extract the package contents and inspect the AppxBlockMap.xml file. The HashMethod attribute of the BlockMap element indicates the hash algorithm that was used when creating the app package. For example:

syntax:

```
<BlockMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/blockmap" 
HashMethod="https://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256">
```

- Step 2: Run SignTool.exe to sign the package

**To sign the package with a signing certificate from a .pfx file**

syntax

```
SignTool sign /fd hashAlgorithm /a /f signingCert.pfx /p password filepath.appx
```

SignTool defaults the /fd hashAlgorithm parameter to SHA1 if it's not specified, and SHA1 isn't valid for signing app packages. So, you must specify this parameter when you sign an app package. To sign an app package that was created with the default SHA256 hash, you specify the /fd hashAlgorithm parameter as SHA256:

syntax

```
SignTool sign /fd SHA256 /a /f signingCert.pfx /p password filepath.appx
```

You can omit the /p password parameter if you use a .pfx file that isn't password protected. You can also use other certificate selection options that are supported by SignTool to sign app packages. For more info about these options, see SignTool.

If you want to time stamp the app package, you must do it during the sign operation. For example:

syntax

```
SignTool sign /fd hashAlgorithm /a /f signingCert.pfx /p password /tr timestampServerUrl 
filepath.appx
```

Make the /tr timestampServerUrl parameter equal to the URL for an RFC 3161 time stamp server.